# CreateMediaWithIdentity/CreateContentWithIdentity without raising events in Umbraco

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I am using Umbraco 7 and have written some custom code on the following events

```
Umbraco.Core.Services.MediaService.Saved += new Umbraco.Core.Events.TypedEventHandler<IMediaService, Umbraco.Core.Events.SaveEventArgs<IMedia>>(MediaService_Published); 

Umbraco.Core.Services.ContentService.Saved += new Umbraco.Core.Events.TypedEventHandler<IContentService, Umbraco.Core.Events.SaveEventArgs<IContent>>(ContentService_Published);
```

For content, I am generating a media folder and vice versa.

The following code causes the other method to be fired.

```
var newContent = contentService.CreateContentWithIdentity(mediaItem.Name, obj.Id, "SomeContentAlias");
```

and...

```
var newMedia = mediaService.CreateMediaWithIdentity(contentItem.Name, obj.Id, "SomeMediaAlias");
```

I have used the save method to update nodes before, and that has a parameter of raised events...

```
contentService.Save(contentItem, 0, false);
```

Is there some way I can create a new media item with an identity and suppress the event being raised?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. See [CreateMediaWithIdentity](https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/dev-v7/src/Umbraco.Core/Services/MediaService.cs#L148).

Of course you also didn't suppress raising events for creating new content (see [CreateContentWithIdentity](https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/dev-v7/src/Umbraco.Core/Services/ContentService.cs#L248), you only suppressed events for SAVING a content item. This you can do with a media item in exactly the same way, by setting `raiseEvents` to false:

```
mediaService.Save(newMedia, 0, false);
```